# What does functionOfA(int a[]) do?

Tags: java

I am currently trying to figure out what a certain method does so as to proceed to annotate it, providing a post condition and loop invariant.

**What I've figured out:**

- On a positive and negative array, all positive `x` becomes positive upon the first time the minimum is encountered.
- When the array is all negative, `x` and `y` are the sum of the elements.

Anyone see another approach to analyzing this method? Thank you for your time.

Java Code:

```
public class funA {
    public static void functionOfA(int a[]) {
      int MAXINT = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      int x = MAXINT; 
      int y = MAXINT; 
      int i = 0;
      int n = a.length;

      while(i != n) {
        if(y == MAXINT) {
          y = a[i];
          x = min(x, y);
          System.out.println("x: " + x + " y: " + y); 
          i= i+1;
        } else {
          y = min(y + a[i], a[i]);
          x= min(x, y);
          System.out.println("x: " + x + " y: " + y); 
          i= i+1;
        }  
      }
      System.out.println(x + " " + y);
  }

  public static int min(int x, int y) {
    if(x < y) {
      return x;
    } else {
      return y;
    }
  }

  public static void main (String args[]) {
    int a[]= new int[] { 0, -9, 3, 2, -4, 3, -12, 3, 1 };
    functionOfA(a);
    for(int i= 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(a[i]+ " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    int a2[]= new int[] { -9, -3, -10, -4, -2 };
    functionOfA(a2);
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < a2.length; i2++) {
      System.out.print(a2[i2]+ " ");
    }
  }
}
```

By the way this was the given:

```
int x = MAXINT; int y = MAXINT; int i = 0;
int a[n];

while (i != n) {
  y = min(y + a[i], a[i]);
  x = min(x, y);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Whoever wrote that function should be taken out and shot.. maybe tarred and feathered beforehand. Assuming `MAXINT` can never happen because in the input or through overflow (otherwise god knows what'll happen), on first glance I think we basically just sum up all negative numbers in the array.

Comment: I'm betting on research academia code over homework.  Does a task that doesn't make sense in a terrible way.  If this is production code in a live system though...

Answer (score 4):

The output is a negative number equal to the largest(abs value) sum of consecutive negative numbers

```
-1, -1, -1, 5, 4, 3, -10  -> -10
-3, -4, -5, 5, 4, 3, -10  -> -12
```

As to WHY someone would do that, I don't know.  Project euler?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the function is searching for the subsequence with the least possible sum.

edit @Thomas: Close, but the subsequence that is summed may contain positive numbers. Eg, modify one of your examples (-3, -4, -5, 5, 4, 3, -10 => -12) slightly: -3, -4, -5, 5, 4, -10 => -13 (the sum of the entire array).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the method functionOfA is trying to determine the minimum value in the array a[ ]

Answer (score 0):

With this input:

```
int [] a = {-1,2,3,777,-777,-20,30,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,8,8,8,8,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
```

Your program produces:

```
x: -1 y: -1
x: -1 y: 1
x: -1 y: 3
x: -1 y: 777
x: -777 y: -777
x: -797 y: -797
x: -797 y: -767
x: -797 y: -677
x: -797 y: -677
x: -797 y: -677
x: -797 y: -677
x: -797 y: -677
x: -797 y: -677
x: -797 y: -677
x: -797 y: -677
x: -797 y: -677
x: -797 y: -669
x: -797 y: -661
x: -797 y: -653
x: -797 y: -645
x: -797 y: -637
x: -797 y: -637
x: -797 y: -636
x: -797 y: -635
x: -797 y: -634
x: -797 y: -633
x: -797 y: -632
x: -797 y: -631
x: -797 y: -630
x: -797 y: -629
x: -797 y: -628
x: -797 y: -627
x: -797 y: -626
x: -797 y: -625
x: -797 y: -624
-797 -624
```

Makes no sense to me...